# How to filter values of an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I will describe the situation for more clarity. I have an array
like this

```
animalsArray = {
animalID : number,
animalName: string,
animalDescription: string,

animalChild: animalsArray[]

}
```

Now I have to filter these animals using `animalName` from user input by textfield. Some animals can have n number of `animalChild` or non at all or `animalChild` can have another `animalChild` inside it.

I already have a code like this

```
public animalsArray:animalsArray[]

    this.filteredanimalsArray.next(
                this.animalsArray.filter(item => (item.animalName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1))
            );
```

To filter the main `animalsArray` and it works fine but the user input doesn't go through the child arrays.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Will edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use recursivity like this :

```js
function filterAnimals(animals, name) {
    return animals.filter(animal => {
        const matching = animal.animalName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();
        const hasChildMatch = Array.isArray(animal.animalChild) && filterAnimals(animal.animalChild, name).length > 0;
        return matching || hasChildMatch;
    });
}

const search = 'leon';
const filterdAnimals = filterAnimals(animalsArray, search);
```